# Can I modify my existing JavaScript code to use PKCS5 padding in TripleDES encryption?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs, tripledes

I need to encrypt a file using TripleDES, ECB and PKCS5 padding. I haven't found in forums or in stackoverflow any answer, due to the fact that they always use Pkcs7 on TripleDES, and i need Pkcs5. Right now this code doesn't work when i send it to the server for desencryption.

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var fileData = event.target.result;

                    var key = "123456789";
                    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

                    var encryptedData = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(fileData, keyBytes, {
                        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                    });

                    var fileEnc = new Blob([encryptedData]);

                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileEnc);
                    var filename = file.name + ".enc";
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Is there any way of doing the same code but with pkcs5? Or any JavaScript library which could help me use it instead of CryptoJS?

Comment: Without going into a long explanation, for the purposes of padding of block ciphers, every modern software library uses the scheme from PKCS7 for padding. This includes Java, which labels their padding scheme PKCS5. It's really PKCS7. And for TripleDES, the PKCS5 and PKCS7 schemes are identical anyway.